# Android listviewadapter radio button setChecked the first item and when clicking the othe item the first item will be uncheck

Tags: android

i have a listview with radio button item.

here is the code in my fragment.

```
ListViewAdapterShipping.AdapterInterface listener = new ListViewAdapterShipping.AdapterInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(String value, String price, String symbol, String name, String desc, String shipicon, String weight, String module){
        textShippingRateId.setText(value);
        textShippingRate.setText(price);
        textSymbol.setText(symbol);
        textNameName.setText(name);
        textDescDesc.setText(desc);
        textShipIcon.setText(shipicon);
        textShipWeight.setText(weight);
        textShipModule.setText(module);
    }
};

shippingrateadapter = new ListViewAdapterShipping(getActivity(), shippingratearraylist, listener);
shippingratelistview.setAdapter(shippingrateadapter);
shippingratelistview.setExpanded(true);
```

i want the first item to be selected on the first load. then when the user click the other item, the first and other item will be uncheck.

here is my adapter.

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ListViewAdapterShipping extends BaseAdapter {

    boolean expanded = false;

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    AdapterInterface listener;

    public interface AdapterInterface
    {
        void onClick(String value, String price, String symbol, String name, String desc, String shipicon, String weight, String module);
    }

    public ListViewAdapterShipping(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, AdapterInterface listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    String mconfiguration_id, mshipping_price, mshipping_symbol, mshipping_title, mshipping_desc, mshipping_icon, mmshipping_icon, mshipping_weight, mmshipping_weight, mshipping_module;

    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private int mSelectedPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView configuration_id;
        RadioButton shipping_title;
        TextView shipping_weight;
        ImageView shipping_icon;
        TextView shipping_price;
        TextView shipping_symbol;
        TextView shipping_desc;
        TextView shippingicon;
        TextView shippingmodule;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shippingrate_item, parent, false);
        resultp = data.get(position);

        configuration_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textconfigurationid);
        shipping_title = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioShippingtitle);
        shipping_weight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textWeight);
        shipping_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shipping_icon);
        shipping_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        shipping_symbol = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSymbol);
        shipping_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
        shippingicon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textshippingicon);
        shippingmodule = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textshippingmodule);

        configuration_id.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.configuration_id));
        shipping_title.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_title));
        shipping_weight.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_weight));
        shipping_price.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_price));
        shipping_symbol.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_symbol));
        shipping_desc.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_desc));
        shippingicon.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_icon));
        shippingmodule.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_module));

        Glide.with(context).load(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_icon)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(shipping_icon);
        int color = 0xffffffff;
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

        mconfiguration_id = configuration_id.getText().toString();
        mshipping_price = shipping_price.getText().toString();
        mshipping_symbol = shipping_symbol.getText().toString();
        mshipping_title = shipping_title.getText().toString();
        mshipping_desc = shipping_desc.getText().toString();
        mshipping_icon = shippingicon.getText().toString();
        mshipping_weight = shipping_weight.getText().toString();
        mshipping_module = shippingmodule.getText().toString();
        if(mshipping_icon.matches("")){
            mmshipping_icon = "null";
        }else{
            mmshipping_icon =  mshipping_icon;
        }
        if(mshipping_weight.matches("")){
            mmshipping_weight = "null";
        }else{
            mmshipping_weight =  mshipping_weight;
        }
        shipping_title.setTag(mconfiguration_id + "#" + mshipping_price + "#" + mshipping_symbol + "#" + mshipping_title + "#" + mshipping_desc + "#" + mmshipping_icon + "#" + mmshipping_weight + "#" +mshipping_module);
        shipping_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;

                Log.e("mSelectedRB",Integer.toString(mSelectedPosition));

                String CurrentString;
                CurrentString = v.getTag().toString();
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, "#");
                String mconfiguration_id = tokens.nextToken();
                String mshipping_price = tokens.nextToken();
                String mshipping_symbol = tokens.nextToken();
                String mshipping_title = tokens.nextToken();
                String mshipping_desc = tokens.nextToken();
                String mmshipping_icon = tokens.nextToken();
                String mmshipping_weight = tokens.nextToken();
                String mshipping_module = tokens.nextToken();

                if(listener != null)
                    listener.onClick(mconfiguration_id, mshipping_price, mshipping_symbol, mshipping_title, mshipping_desc, mmshipping_icon, mmshipping_weight, mshipping_module);
            }

        });

        if(mSelectedPosition != position){
            shipping_title.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            shipping_title.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && shipping_title != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = shipping_title;
            }
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

as you can see in my adapter the `private int mSelectedPosition = 0;` is set to zero, this means the first item is checked. but when i click the other item. the first item is still checked.

Comment: not so efficient `ListView.invalidateViews` more efficient: google for "redraw a single row in a listview"

Comment: In Onclick once you done with setting selected position try notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: @shreyashmashru thank you..

Comment: working ? should i post as answer ?

Comment: yes working.. yes post your answer. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnClick once you are done with setting selected position you have to do **notifydatasetchanged**.
More Info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one counter to check which position is checked.Declare it as global variable.

```
private int mCheckedPosition=-1;
```

Then on clicking any item save the checked position and use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify that the data go changed.

On clicking the checkbox inside the onclick method add this.

```
mCheckedPosition=position;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then in your getView method

```
if(mCheckedPosition==-1){

     //set first view as checked initially

}else if(mCheckedPosition==position){

    //set the clicked view as checked

}else{

    //set the other views unchcked
}
```